# Is it possible to organize cluster of docker machines in local network to improve resource utilization?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

At work we have very powerful workstations and they are not utilized on 100%. Sometimes only IDE is running on them and a few browser windows.

Is there a preferable way to organize a cluster of docker machines in our local network with service discovery to run some useful things like performance or stress tests, build jobs etc.

I've heard good things about Mesos, but not really familiar with it.

It would be really appreciated if you can point me to further readings or practical examples.

To give you more details:

- most of workstations are running on Windows 10
- all machines are isolated to 192.168.37.x subnet

What are the other concerns for that idea? Security?

Comment: I like the idea of running builds on idle machines. I hear about company that is trying similar approach with rendering. Basically they have render farm but workstations are so powerful so they can speed up rendering time especially when people are at home or lunch. Mesos Agent could be installed on Windows but I don't know how it works. Check out other services like Nomad or maybe just Jenkins.

Comment: @janisz, thanks for the comment!
Nomad looks promising, I'll check it out. Not sure about Jenkins slaves though